# No me inserta los datos Php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

Sucedió que el otro día hice un formulario para insertar datos de una publicación para después almacenarla, antes me funcionó pero ahora no, no entiendo, he revisado mi código y no encuentro explicación, por favor ayúdenme, no me muestra errores de sintaxis pero si al revisar la tabla no me inserta nada.

Aquí les dejo mi código, los campos de mi tabla son `Titulo`, `Fecha`, `Descripción`, `Imagen`, la primera con mayúscula, los campos de texto que valido del formulario son `campo_titulo`, `area_descripcion`, `la imagen` y `la fecha` las recojo; lo pueden ver en la función insertar.

```
         <?php

          $host ="localhost";
          $usuario = "root";
          $clave = "";
          $bd = "seguridad";

      $conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$bd);

      if ($_FILES['imagen'] ['error'] ) {
     switch ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['error'] ) {
     case 1 :
     echo "El envio del archivo se a interrumpido";
     break;
     case 2 :
     echo "No se envio el archivo debido a una lenta conexión";
     break;
                                      }

    } else {
    echo "No hay error en la trasnferencia de archivo";
    if ( (isset ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']) && ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) ) ) 
        {
        $destino_de_ruta="imagenes/";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['imagen'] ['tmp_name'], $destino_de_ruta . $_FILES ['imagen'] 
        ['name']);
        echo "el archivo se a copiado en el directorio de imagenes";


        }

  }

 $titulo = $_POST['campo_titulo'];
 $fecha = date ("y-m-d");
 $descripcion = $_POST['area_descripcion'];
 $imagen =$_FILES ['imagen'] ['name'];

 mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO contenido (Titulo, Fecha, Descripcion, Imagen) values 
    ('$titulo', '$fecha', '$descripcion', '$imagen')");
  echo "Se agrego tu publicación con exito";
```

?>

Comment: Hola, ahora mismo me pillas oxidado con php. Los datos, imagino que los recibes de un formulario html no? Despues de $conexion en el if, no haces el isset, no se comprueba que te este llegando el dato. Cuando hacia php, hacia 2 comprobaciones, el isset y comprobar que llegaran por post, puede ser eso un error?

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo de una query propia, deberias probar de pasarlos asi con comillas a los datos: $query_insert_prov = "INSERT INTO persona (`pers_nomb`,`pers_apel`,`pers_dni`,`pers_dir`,`pers_tel`,`pers_fecnac`,`tipo_usuario_tipo_usu_id`,`pers_sexo`, `pers_email` ) VALUES ('" . $nombre . "','" . $apellido . "','" . $dni . "','" . $direccion . "','" . $telefono . "','" . $fnac . "','" . $tipo_usuario . "' ,'" . $sexo . "','" . $email . "')";
$result = mysql_query($query_insert_prov) or die('No se pudo ejecutar persona');

Comment: amigo use tu codigo y me quedo asi $query_insert_con = "INSERT INTO contenido (Titulo, Fecha, Descripcion, Imagen) VALUES ('" . $titulo . "','" . $fecha . "','" . $descripcion . "','" . $imagen . "')"; $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query_insert_con) or die('No se pudo ejecutar contenido');
le puse $conexion por que cuando lo mande a eecutar me pidio ese parametro y me pidio mysqli no mysql, pero no me inserta nada, me imprime no se puedo ejectuar  contenido y en la tabla no aparece ningun registro :( ayuda

Comment: Podrías hacer un var_dump de tus variables que insertas por favor. `var_dump($titulo);  var_dump($fecha);  var_dump($descripcion); var_dump($imagen);`
Y de igual forma de tu consulta por favor. `$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "query"); var_dump($result);`

Comment: amigo lo hice de esta forma siguiendo tu consejo pero no me inserta :( no se si puse algo mal ?
  $query_insert_con = "INSERT INTO contenido (Titulo, Fecha, Descripcion, Imagen) VALUES 
var_dump($titulo); var_dump($fecha); var_dump($descripcion); var_dump($imagen;)"; $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "$query_insert_con"); var_dump($result) or die('No se pudo ejecutar contenido');


  ?>

Comment: Haciendo un var_dump($result) luego de hacer todo el insert que te pase, deberias poder ver algun dato que te trae

Comment: Le pongo esa linea después del inset que me pasaste, lo intentaré

Comment: Consulta, tu código "switch ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['error'] )" retorna un valor numérico, ya que switch solo acepta ese tipo de valor?